# Disabling Eclipse **VARIABLES** auto completion

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, autocomplete, settings

As the title says I want to disable `Eclipse` auto completion for **VARIABLES** names.

Like when i start to type `String s` and then space it completes the variable name to string. But i want it to be s. I know I can use `Esc` when the suggestion comes and keep going , but still, there is a way in `Eclipse` to disable this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto completion is controlled by Content Assist. The settings for this are at: "Window -> Preferences" then "Java -> Editor -> Content Assist". But there is no option to specifically exclude only Java variables.

Comment: Just what i though. Thank you.